# Count cells in a column between values until specific value reached in Google Sheets - Multiple Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I am trying to do a tricky conditional count on a dataset. I need to count the number of rows that meet a set of criteria (after a specific date, a certain category) that sums up to a set limit - that is, I am counting how many days between now until the sum of the "Forecast" is a certain value.

[image]

So in this instance, I would want to count up the # of forecast rows that were = Category 1, Date starting 12/27, until the Forecast column sums less than or equal to $20,000. The desired answer would be 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why my result is 1?
I created the sample based on your picture and I use **SUMPRODUCT** function to get the result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$19>=$F$2)*($A$2:$A$19=$F$3)*($C$2:$C$19<=$F$4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This answered my question and was the perfect formula. The only reason your answer and my desired answer differed is because we used different #s (2000 vs 20000)